# In C ++, how to execute the second 'system()' only after the first one is over?

Tags: c++, windows

See the code below. If there is any alternative to system that does what I want it would be good too.

```
strcat(comando1,"start c:\\arquiv~1\\winrar\\rar a D:\\sisbibbkp\\teste1");
strcat(comando1,data);
strcat(comando1,".rar E:\\softwares");
system(comando1);

strcat(comando2,"start c:\\arquiv~1\\winrar\\rar a D:\\sisbibbkp\\teste2");
strcat(comando2,data);
strcat(comando2,".rar E:\\softwares");
system(comando2);  // I want this system to run only after system (command1) finishes.
```

Comment: What you are doing is not suitable for C++. You have `.BAT` and `PowerShell` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `start` command runs things as a separate job:

```
C:\Users\Pax> start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
```

If you want to wait for it to finish, just remove the `start` from the command.

Or if you want the whole *thing* to run separately but have step 2 wait for step 1 to finish, put both into a `cmd` script (without the `start` bits) and `start cmd.exe` on your script to do it.

That should start a separate job to run the script but that job will run the command in the script sequentially.

Comment: So the solution is simple, just remove start.

Comment: Or keep `start` (which [does more](https://superuser.com/a/1512003/64178) and thus [can be of use](https://superuser.com/a/466686/64178)) and add `/WAIT`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is to not use `system()` at all. Use [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) instead to run `rar.exe` directly, and then you can wait on the spawned process.

```cpp
std::string comando1 = "c:\\arquiv~1\\winrar\\rar.exe a D:\\sisbibbkp\\teste1" + std::string(data) + ".rar E:\\softwares";

STARTUPINFOA si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, const_cast<char*>(comando1.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}

std::string comando2 = "c:\\arquiv~1\\winrar\\rar.exe a D:\\sisbibbkp\\teste2" + std::string(data) + ".rar E:\\softwares";

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, const_cast<char*>(comando2.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

A better solution is to use a library that handles RAR files directly in your own process, don't shell out to `rar.exe` at all. You can use WinRAR's `UnRar.dll` for that, or any number of 3rd party libraries that are available.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `/WAIT` after `start`.

That makes the process block until the subprocess has completed.

Moving away from `start` is fine if that's what you want, but it [has other consequences](https://superuser.com/a/466686/64178). `start` [does more things](https://superuser.com/a/1512003/64178) than alternatives.